# mysql update statement always inserts

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and I want to update if $mail is already in database, and insert if its not, but it always insert, no matter what, if the mail already exists, it inserts a new row with the same mail. help me please, Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../conexion.php';

$nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
$apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
$mail=$_POST['Mail'];
$telefono=$_POST['Telefono'];
$ultimaventa=$_POST['Numeroventa'];
$totalcomprado=0;
$ultimomonto=$_POST['Total'];
$resultado=mysqli_query($con,"select * from clientes")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$existe=false;

while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
if($f['Mail']!=$mail){
    $totalcomprado=$ultimomonto;
    $existe=false;
    }else{
        if($f['Mail'==$mail]){
            $totalcomprado=$f['totalcomprado']+$ultimomonto; 
            $existe=true;
            }
    }
}


if($existe==false){
    mysqli_query($con,"insert into      clientes(nombre,apellido,Mail,telefono,ultimaventa,ultimomonto,totalcomprado)values(
    '".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$mail."','".$telefono."','".$ultimaventa."','".$ultimomonto."','".$ultimomonto."')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }

if($existe==true){
    mysqli_query($con,"update clientes SET nombre='".$nombre."', apellido='".$apellido."',Mail='".$mail."',telefono='".$telefono."',ultimaventa='".$ultimaventa."',ultimomonto='".$ultimomonto."',totalcomprado='".$totalcomprado."' WHERE Mail='".$mail."'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

Comment: `if($f['Mail'==$mail]){` misplaced `]`, that's why you'll never get `$existe==true`.

Comment: what do u mean with 'misplaced' mfoster?

Comment: It's supposed to be `$f['Mail']==$mail`. Look at the position of `]`

Comment: pfffffffff, I feel really dumb, thank u again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern of `if(bool) {} else if (!bool) {}` can easily, easily lead to bugs if you're not careful. In these cases, just use an else-statement:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../conexion.php';

$nombre        = $_POST['Nombre'];
$apellido      = $_POST['Apellido'];
$mail          = $_POST['Mail'];
$telefono      = $_POST['Telefono'];
$ultimaventa   = $_POST['Numeroventa'];
$totalcomprado = 0;
$ultimomonto   = $_POST['Total'];
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, "select 1 from clientes WHERE Mail='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mail) . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$existe = mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0;

if ($existe) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE clientes SET nombre='" . $nombre . "', apellido='" . $apellido . "',Mail='" . $mail . "',telefono='" . $telefono . "',ultimaventa='" . $ultimaventa . "',ultimomonto='" . $ultimomonto . "',totalcomprado=totalcomprado+'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ultimomonto) . "' WHERE Mail='" . $mail . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO clientes(nombre, apellido, Mail, telefono, ultimaventa, ultimomonto, totalcomprado)values('" . $nombre . "','" . $apellido . "','" . $mail . "','" . $telefono . "','" . $ultimaventa . "','" . $ultimomonto . "','" . $ultimomonto . "')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tought it was working, but sometimes it updates sometimes it adds a new row, repeating mail, what can i do?? i dont get whats wrong

Comment: @LuchoMansilla There are a few other issues. Basically, your $resultado fetches each row in clientes. Going through your while-loop, $existe toggles between true and false, true and false. That makes the last check on $existe pretty random whether it inserts or updates. You may want to use MySQL's ability to "[INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)" and make the mail column a primary key in your database.

Comment: Why not filter the result set by applying `WHERE email=<email>`? Then you know if it exist depending on number of rows. `$existe = <num_rows> != 0`;

Comment: mfoster, you are saying I have to put WHERE in the fetch array statement? or not getting it?, Crhis let me read that, I am new in this, I dunno how it works, thanks

Comment: @LuchoMansilla - I've edited my answer to give an example of what msfoster describes. Basically, resultado will only select 1, and we are setting $existe to true if at least one row is returned. We will be adding $ultimomonto to totalcomprado in the UPDATE statement. Coincidentially, if $ultimomonto is a number of some sort (float, int, etc.), you should make sure that $ultimomonto is in that format.

Comment: As a last suggestion: have a look at prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: It is working! I know about SQL inection and thing, I have to study that,  thanks both of u, I learnt something, =)